# Java - Adding Photo to JFrame

Tags: java

For a school project I need to create a GUI and do some things with it, one of the things is adding an `ImageIcon` to my `JFrame`.

```
public Frame(Pet pet) {
    setTitle("Stay Alive!");
    setResizable(false);
    setSize(400, 550);
    ImageIcon icon = pet.getImageIcon();
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setIcon(icon);
    add(label);
}
`
```

This still shows up blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right way to add an image to your Icon by setting JLabel is on this form

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(animal.getImg());
JLabel thumb = new JLabel();
thumb.setIcon(icon);
```

and url to access the image would be something like

```
"C:\\Users\\Archie King\\Desktop\\School\\Computer Science\\cat.png";
```

Comment: Hmm, I was nearly correct, this seems to work except I'm having trouble with the path. Thank you!

Comment: Try with double-backslash (i.e. Users\\Archie King\\Desktop...)

Comment: Hi, I just changed the code, I'm using a URL now.

For some reason the image still isn't showing up.

Comment: Yeah the URL wouldn't work, so I went to a file name..
String path = "C:\\Users\\Archie King\\Desktop\\School\\Computer Science\\cat.png";

The problem is with instantiating the ImageIcon..

new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path)) is wrong,

Comment: Fixed. I was using the arguments wrong.
Thanks very much!